# How to generate role_id and secret_id for HarshiCorp Vault

Tags: node.js, spring, security, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am working on a application which uses Vault.

Now, the vault needs **Role_Id** and **Secret_Id** to be delivered in order to fetch value for a key.

Both these role_id and secret_id are kept in *environment variable.*

I can't figure out **how to get/retrieve these role and secret id from HarshiCorp Vault.**

I have the UI for vault opened up but I can't figure out *how to generate these 2 values.*

Anyone can provide the **steps** will be great!

Answer (score 0):

`role_id` and `secret_id` are the credentials leased via Vault AppRole authentication method.

You can follow the examples [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle#configuration) adapting to your use case